# Who or what was controlling Batman when he painted this room yellow?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, green-lantern

I recently came across this bizarre comic book page from All-Star Batman and Robin #9:

[image: Batman, drinking lemonade in a room with everything, including batman is painted yellow except for Green Lantern.]

(Bizarre because of the writing, not the yellow paint)

Clearly that's not Batman, but I couldn't find a source as to who or what is controlling him. It must have been much further back. It reminds me of when Doctor Octopus

> took control of Spider-Man

What happened to Batman in this case? Possession or some other control of him?

Comment: Are you aware that most incarnations of Green Lantern are unable to effect anything in the color yellow?

Comment: @Politank-Z yes

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260998/what-is-the-nature-of-the-relationship-between-the-frank-miller-batman-and-the-b

Comment: Is that supposed to be yellow paint?  Or is it gold?  To me it looks like it's got a metallic sheen like the whole room and everything in it was plated in gold - or maybe he's got the Midas curse or something...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it's yellow

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> What happened to Batman in this case?

Frank Miller happened.

Batman isn't being possessed or controlled or anything of the sort. This, to the best of my knowledge, is simply how Batman was written for the entirety of *All-Star Batman and Robin*. Lest we forget that this is the same comic that gave us the infamous line:

> What, are you dense? Are you retarded or something? Who the hell do you think I am? I'm the Goddamn Batman.

No in-story justification is ever provided for what *All-Star Batman and Robin* Batman is so uncharacteristically psychopathic and violent. He just *is*. It's one of the main reasons the series is so reviled, and the only real explanation anyone can offer is that Frank Miller was trying *way* too hard to be dark and edgy and completely derailed Batman's character in the process.

Comment: Oh wow. That's something else.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this Batman isn't the mainstream comics Batman. This is the same alternate reality Batman who first appeared in Frank Miller's _The Dark Knight Returns_ miniseries. _All Star Batman & Robin_ is a prequel to that miniseries.

Comment: Nah man this isn’t Batman, it’s “Crazy Steve” a person who knocked out Bruce Wayne and took over the Batman persona for ASBaR. At least according to one comic reviewer

Comment: "And Now for Something Completely Different"